# CSS3 Stylesheet Template

Tags: templates, css, frameworks, stylesheet

I was looking around and could not find a CSS3 Template to use as a basic starting template. I was wondering if anybody knows if something like this even exists. Basically, I am looking for a basic stylesheet to start off with that includes all of the basic selectors so that I can fill them in or remove if not needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[The Wikipedia article on CSS frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_frameworks) has a list of popular frameworks and some useful stats about them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to twitter bootstrap : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
or to fundation (because everybody uses bootstrap, and all sites look the same) : http://foundation.zurb.com/

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Mind if I introduce you to [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) template?

It is a CSS3 template framework.

This is just a suggestion, since it helped me a lot to learn more about CSS3 and at the same time insight to [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

If you decided to go ahead with twitter bootstrap go to this [link](http://www.queness.com/post/11632/18-useful-twitter-boostrap-goodies-you-should-know) for more resources.